# Data Studio - Can you display the date of a Max Metric within a Chart?

Tags: looker-studio

I am working on creating a table that displays the Max Value of a metric that exists across several different dimensions. I'd like to be able to have the date that max value was recorded within the table as well. Essentially we want to know what our current "record" is and when it was reached.

If I add the "date" as a dimension, the chart then pulls in every record rather than just the max for the other dimensions.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c47eba76-c694-4a27-b13d-8f192c90e491) to demonstrate. One way it could be achieved is using the [NARY_MAX](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583429) function:

> **1) Create a  [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044)**
>   - ***Dimension***: Date
>
> **2) Metric ([Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685))**
>   - ***[NARY_MAX](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583429)***: The formula takes the MAX value in each row from the fields specified, for example (using 3 fields to demonstrate, although more or fewer fields could be used based on the use case):
>
> ```
> NARY_MAX(Field_1, Field_2, Field_3, Field_n)
> ```
>
> **3) Sort**
>   - ***Rows per page***: 1
>   - ***Sort***: NARY_MAX (Field created in #2 above) in Descending order

[image]