# How can I put the peak time of a metric on the table

Tags: looker-studio

For example, I have the following data from the data source:

| Platform (Text) | Timestamp (Date & Time) | Sales (Number) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EC_Platform_A | 20230501000000 | 7442 |
| EC_Platform_B | 20230501000000 | 4213 |
| EC_Platform_A | 20230502000000 | 6708 |
| EC_Platform_B | 20230502000000 | 5022 |
| EC_Platform_A | 20230503000000 | 6923 |
| EC_Platform_B | 20230503000000 | 4863 |
| EC_Platform_A | 20230504000000 | 5882 |
| EC_Platform_B | 20230504000000 | 4920 |
| EC_Platform_A | 20230505000000 | 8011 |
| EC_Platform_B | 20230505000000 | 5221 |
| EC_Platform_A | 20230506000000 | 10223 |
| EC_Platform_B | 20230506000000 | 6743 |
| EC_Platform_A | 20230507000000 | 10418 |
| EC_Platform_B | 20230507000000 | 6647 |

I want a summary table that can output a table like:

| Platform | Average | Peak day | Peak Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EC_Platform_A | 7944 | May 7, 2023 | 10418 |
| EC_Platform_B | 5376 | May 6, 2023 | 6743 |

By configuring the table with:

- Dimensions

  - Platform
- Metrics

  - Average = `ROUND(AVG(Sales))`
  - Peak Day= ?????? <== Not sure how I can calculate this.
  - Peak Sales = `ROUND(MAX(Sales))`

How can I configure `Peak day` for the table?

I wrote the custom connector for this data source.

Although having the capability to do so, it doesn't make sense for me to add a field just for calculating, in this case, `Peak day` for this specific table.

---

I've seen the answer of [Data Studio - Can you display the date of a Max Metric within a Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863898) and the example report inside.

As the table in the example report sorts the value while limiting the table row to 1, this method in that report doesn't seems to fit my use case.